# What type of ribbon connector is this?

Tags: ribbon-cable

I'd like to know what type of cable this is. It looks very similar to the types used in phones and tablets and is for a camera. I need a replacement and would appreciate any help to locate the correct part.

[image: Ribbon cable]

[image]

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: "FFC/FPC cable" is what you are looking for. One cut like that which is not straight is probably custom though. That might actually classify more as a flex PCB than FFC/FPC cable.

Comment: Are you looking for the flat-flex or the connectors on the ends of it?

Comment: You might want to specify the equipment make and model from where this cable comes from, otherwise the chances of us suggesting were to find it are very slim.

Comment: *" I need a replacement"* You could just fix the connections using wires. Check which one(s) is/are broken and bypass it/them.

Comment: @Oldfart - look like the housing molding of J1 is broken...  Bilal - some measurements would be useful to identifying - length, width and pin spacing.

Comment: It's flex PCB, and it's custom made.  So you're not going to be able to just swap out the whole thing unless you can get your hands on a the same make & model of equipment that's broken some other way than yours.

Comment: Thanks for the replies, sorry didn't realise I should have been more specific, it is for a SV SenseView Duo portable magnifier. I couldn't get an exact measurement but roughly 4mm between 11 pins. I did try to fix it but destroyed it in the process...

Comment: I'm looking for a ribbon with the same connectors and pin configuration, even if it is straight and not the same shape, just as long as it works.

Comment: Have you tried to contact the manufacturer of this SenseView Duo magnifier to see if they could send you a replacement part? Or looked on ebay for the same thing sold as "for parts"? Failing that, it would be simple, if kind of expensive, to draw up a roughly-equivalent flex pcb in KiCad and get it printed from a cheap PCB fab.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a flex cable for phone battery. Contact manufacturer to get replacement  cable or if someone makes it aftermarket. If replacing battery, flex cable comes with it.